# Exclude specific group/users from ForceCommand in OpenSSH ssd_config

Tags: sftp, openssh, sshd, chroot

I want to make `ForceCommand internal-sftp` and `ChrootDirectory /jail` the default for all users accessing a server via SSH. Only users in a certain group are allowed to escape this.

How can I exclude a certain group from `ForceCommand internal-sftp` in a `Match` block?

It's possible to reset `ChrootDirectory` by assigning a `none` value.

Matching the group and setting`ForceCommand none` doesn't work (probably because there is no "none" program), `ForceCommand bash` works for shell access, but SFTP will no longer work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works for me with OpenSSH 5.1:

set a restricted default for everyone, but let the staff group have the (unrestricted) defaults.

```
Match Group *,!staff
        ChrootDirectory /home/ftp
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```